# Java DB error when creating a table in Netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, javadb

I am creating a table within my database in Netbeans (Java DB).

I have created the database and I am connected to it.

This is my first and only table:

[image]

and the error I am receiving is this:

[image]

I am an amateur when it comes to databases and I have tried searching high and low to find what I'm doing wrong. I've tried:

- Changing the table name to all lower case, all capitals and how it is now too.
- Changing the primary key.
- Changing the column names.
- Changing the size of the column uid (which is fixed to 0 unless the data type is changed  - I assume for obvious reasons this is correct anyway)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` is a reserved keyword in many databases.  You should choose another name, or add quotation marks (`"`) around the table name.

Comment: Thanks! - Decided to call it Person.